# Why am I seeing "*QUERYSTRINGPII_REMOVED*" in the query string of a lot of requests

Tags: data-uri, mod-security

I regularly see URIs like the following that contain `*QUERYSTRINGPII_REMOVED*` and the IDS blows them away without further examination. I could just allow the asterisk character but it isn't legitimate for any of our pages. Is there some software people have on their machine that is perhaps redacting what it sees as credit card numbers or otherwise sensitive info? A Google search shows this on quite a few places, not just my site.

```
GET /Private/Info/SomePage?ItemID=a23458575d2&*QUERYSTRINGPII_REMOVED* HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: "allow the asterisk character" - what do you mean by this? Is your system currently rejecting (by the IDS?) these URLs because they contain an asterisk in the query string? What part of the query string has actually been removed?

Comment: I think they he means that because they are not part of the "ItemID" parameter, his webserver does not pay attention to them.

Comment: Is there a referrer logged with these requests?   If these URLs are indexed in Google, does Google Search Console list them and tell you where they are linked?

Comment: The "PII" in that stands for "Personally Identifiable Information".

Comment: Is it possible that there is sometimes a parameter like `email=foo@example.com` on the URL in that place?

Comment: user82217-We don't use the asterisk in our URIs, yes the IDS is blocking it.  Stephen-It was actually put in another field due to the ampersand. Great call on "Personally Identifiable Information" - that makes a lot of sense. You may be right about the email address, any idea of what software would be doing this?

Comment: Google seems to index quite a few of these URLs.   If you search for QUERYSTRINGPII_REMOVED on Google you get lots of pages that contain it in the URL.   That means that either Google itself is censoring the PII in the URLs in the search results, or Googlebot is finding links that do so.   I haven't been able to track down any links so far, so I'm leaning towards Google doing it.   The only thing that makes me doubt that is that Bing also finds URLs like that.